# In what platform memmove and memcpy can have significant performance difference?

Tags: c++, c, performance

I understand that `memmove` and `memcpy` difference is that `memmove` handles the memory overlap case. I have checked the implementation in libgcc and got this article [[memcpy performance]](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/memcpy-performance) from the intel website.

In libgcc, the `memmove` is similar to `memcpy`, both just go though one byte and byte, so the performance should be almost same even after optimization.

Someone has measured this and got this article [memcopy, memmove, and Speed over Safety](http://vgable.com/blog/2008/05/24/memcopy-memmove-and-speed-over-safety/). Even I don't think the `memmove` can be faster than `memcpy`, but there should be no big difference at least on `Intel` platform.

So in what platform and how, `memcpy` can be significantly faster than `memmove`, if there is none, why providing two similiar functions instead of just `memmove`, and lead to a lots of bug.

Edit: I'm not asking the difference of memmove and memcpy, I know memmove can handle overlap issue. The question is about is there really any platform where memcpy is faster than memmove?

Comment: If I remember well there is some issues related to overlapping memory addresses

Comment: There are lots of questions already on `memcpy` vs. `memmove` (see the "Related" bar on the right).  Are you sure that your question isn't already covered by one of those?

Comment: The standard is **not** about the Intel platform.

Comment: Commenters, please read the *whole* question. It seems he knows what the difference in the definition is, but that it seems in practice to make no difference. The question is "on which platforms *does* it matter?"

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, I'm not asking the difference of memmove and memcpy, I know memmove can handle overlap issue. The question is about does there really any platform memcpy is faster than memmove?

Comment: This question is *not* a duplicate of those listed!

Comment: @BoBTFish *Reading* a question before marking it as a duplicate is not the SO way. You're getting in the way of Progress(tm). `</sarcasm>`

Comment: @Suma, It should not because of historic reason, because you can just fix memcpy to make it safe instead of introduce memmove.

Comment: It's been done, C11 added memcpy_s.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is at least one recent case where the constraint of non-overlapping memory is used to generate faster code:

In Visual Studio `memcpy` can be compiled using [intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzkfha43.aspx), while `memmove` cannot. This leads in `memcpy` being much faster for small regions of a known size because of removing the function call and setup overhead. The implementation using `movsd`/`movsw`/`movsb` is not suitable for overlapping blocks, as it starts copying at the lowest address, incrementing the edi/esi during the copy.

See also [Make compiler copy characters using movsd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1137515/16673).

The [GCC also lists](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) memcpy as implemented as built-ins, the implementation and motivation is likely to be similar to that of Visual Studio.

Comment: But Why movsd/movsw/movsb doesn't suit for overlap copy? If all parameter is known, compiler can also chose movsd or movsw

Comment: ok I understand it. Most of the time only the block size is compile time constant.

Comment: movsX instructions always move in one direction, starting at the lowest address and incrementing the edi/esi during the copy. The D/W/B only selects unit of copy (DWORD, WORD, BYTE).

Comment: movsb and friends can copy in the other direction. They are controlled by the direction flag. There's no reason memove cannot be as fast as memcpy.  Though not every implementation does so, that's for sure.

Comment: "There's no reason memove cannot be as fast as memcpy" is not completely correct, as mentioned by "The standard is not about the Intel platform" comment. It might be possible to make it as fast on one platform, but there's no guarantee on all possible platforms.

Answer (score -3):

Good practice: In general, USE memmove only if you have to. USE it when there is a very reasonable chance that the source and destination regions are over-lapping.

Otherwise USE memcpy. memcpy is more efficient.

Reference: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yr1YnOVG-4g Dr. Jerry Cain, (Stanford Intro Systems Lecture - 7) Time: 36:00